# Syntax error while executing this query with python in sqlite databse

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table name globalData, in my sqlite database, with column 'index', 'rank_d30'. While executing this query with python, i receive syntax error near ON ...

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO globalData (`index`, rank_d30) VALUES(0, 9) ON CONFLICT(`index`) DO UPDATE SET rank_d30 = VALUES(rank_d30)')
```

How it can be corrected?

Comment: Is your Index, column an identity column?

Comment: I create table from pandas dataframe using this code
df.to_sql('globalData', conn, if_exists='replace', index=True)
not sure whether it is identity or not

Comment: Is this SQLite  or Postgres ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not recognize the `VALUES()` syntax in the `DO UPDATE` clause of the query, as MySQL does in the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax. To refer to the value that was initially given for insert, you must use pseudo-table `excluded` instead.

Consider:

```
INSERT INTO globalData (`index`, rank_d30) 
VALUES(0, 9) 
ON CONFLICT(`index`) DO UPDATE SET rank_d30 = EXCLUDED.rank_d30
```

Note that, for this to work, you need a unique or primary key constraint on column `index`.